# Cannot connect to some wireless networks

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

My wireless network works fine at home, but on some other networks it takes a lot of time to connect. If it does connect on these then I cannot get any DNS replies.

I suspect the wireless module. The adapter is `12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`. The module in use is wl.

Comment: Why do you suspect the driver when it works at home and with some other networks. (Assuming it only fails on some of the other/not-home networks).  Why do you not get any DNS replies? Are the DNS servers on your laptop configured via DHCP? Does the DHCP server reply with any DNS server IPs (that part is OPTIONAL for DNS). Etc etc. Please add more information you your post.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that wl is incorrect for your device: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) I suggest you remove the driver package:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and see if the native driver brcmsmac does a better job.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually more than one adapter with that model name.  To find out which one yours is type into terminal:

lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

My netbook running 14.04 has a broadcom 4313 with 14e4:4727 (rev 01), and what I've done with this adapter (which isn't nearly as pesky in 14.04 as before) is for 4727.

Definitely purge bcmwl-kernel-source as mentioned if you went into "additional drivers" ... unfortunately this isn't always reliable.  I don't use additional drivers anymore.

I installed linux-firmware-nonfree, which was a mistake on my part.  If you installed it yank it.

Follow the steps here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226102&p=13076641#post13076641

I've had lubuntu 14.04, xubuntu 14.04, and now LXDE (14.04 based) and it's worked every time.